# Curl Request In C#

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am trying to curl file contents to an external source. I can curl it correctly from the command line, but I am having problem sending the string in the -d switch in code. Here is the gist of the curl command

```
curl.exe -u userName:password -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X PUT https://someIp/command?filename=filename.txt -d "content of filename.text is here" --insecure
```

I can send the file, and they receive it on the other end, the problem is that the content of the file isn't making it over to them. Does anyone have any experience or ideas here? Here is the code from my proof of concept.

```
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
      System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
      (
        delegate { return true; }
      );

  // create the requst address to send the file to
  string requestAddress = string.Format("{0}{1}", this.CurlAddress, Path.GetFileName(fileName));

  // spin up the request object, set neccessary paramaters
  var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(requestAddress);
  request.ContentType = "text/plain";
  request.Method = "PUT";
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");      

  // open the web request stream
  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    // create a writer to the request stream
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
      // write the text to the stream
      writer.Write(File.ReadAllLines(fileName));

      stream.Close();
    }
  }

  // Get the response
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

  using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Response: {0}", responseString));
  }
```

Comment: Using `HttpClient` with `PutAsync` and `StringContent` might be what you're after.

Comment: Where do you associate the `StringWriter` `writer` with the request stream?

Comment: NetMage, I see what you are saying. The writer isn't associated with the request stream, the string writer is just writing it in to the ether than closing the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't writing the file contents to the stream from the requests .GetRequestStream(). Once I wrote the contents there, it appeared on the other end. New stripped down code is

```
  // open the web request stream
  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);

    stream.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is `Put` with string content. This can easily be done asynchronously with an `HttpClient`.

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task CurlFileContents(Uri uri, string contents)
{
    var content = new StringContent(contents, Encoding.Default, "text/plain");
    var repsonse = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
    var responseContent = await repsonse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //operate on response
}
```